# R 等差数列 初項の違うもの

Tags: r

```
for( i in (3:1))
{
    n=1:10
    an<-i+(n-1)
}
```

上記ですと、複数の数列が作成できません。
初項、１、２、３の数列が一度にできる方法を教えてください。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

```
library(purrr)
map(1:3, `+`, 1:10)
[[1]]
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11

[[2]]
 [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

[[3]]
 [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```